# Add multiple categories to body class Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have found some code which adds the category as a class to the body here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/add-category-name-body_class/ but it only seems to add one category. Does anyone know how to adjust this code so that it can add multiple category classes to the body?

```html
add_filter('body_class','add_category_to_single');
function add_category_to_single($classes, $class) {
  if (is_single() ) {
    global $post;
    foreach((get_the_category($post->ID)) as $category) {
      // add category slug to the $classes array
      $classes[] = $category->category_nicename;
    }
  }
  // return the $classes array
  return $classes;
}
```

Comment: At first sight your code looks good. Just to confirm, does your post have more than 1 category assigned?

Comment: The code looks fine, it should be adding multiple categories to the class. Are you sure that the post is in multiple categories? What do you get if you do a var_dump on (get_the_category($post->ID))?

Comment: The solution by Aaron below worked a treat, but thank you for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION

You can add this code to your custom functions.php file:

```
function add_categories( $classes = '' ) {

    $categories = get_the_category();
    foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    $classes[] = 'category-'.$category->slug;


}
 return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_categories' );
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your functions.php file or visit https://urlzs.com/nESor

```
<?php// extend body_class function 
add_filter('body_class','add_category_to_single');
// create custom function for add class to body element
function add_category_to_single($classes) {
  if (is_single() ) {
    global $post;
    foreach((get_the_category($post->ID)) as $category) {
       // add category slug to the $classes array
      $classes[] = $category->category_nicename;
    }
  }
  // return the $classes array
  return $classes;
}?>
```

Comment: Can you please add explanation what your code does?